# Blazorise components detect changes on bound value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazorise

With the blazor InputField you can detect changes on the bound value like so:

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext">
  <InputText Id="Desc" @bind-Value="@description"></InputText>
</EditForm>
```

and the c#:

```
private LibraryBook libraryBook;
private EditContext EditContext;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    EditContext = new EditContext(libraryBook);
    EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
}

private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff when libraryBook has changed
}
```

I would like the do the same with Blazorise components like so:

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext">
  <TextEdit @bind-Text="@description" />
</EditForm>
```

However whilst binding works fine, it does not trigger OnFieldChanged. Is there a way I can trigger OnFieldChange with Blazorise?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the Blazorise controls don't interact with the `EditContext`.  If you're on Net7.0 you can do this:

```cs
<TextEdit @bind-Text="@description" @bind-Text:after=this.DescriptionUpdated />
```

```cs
    public Task DescriptionUpdated ()
    {
        // do you stuff
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

> Is there a way I can trigger OnFieldChange with Blazorise?

Rewrite it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The TextEdit Blazorise component does not interact with EditContent, however the Validation Blazorise component does. So I am able to handle the OnFieldChanged event via the Validation component's EditContext.

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext">
  <Validations @ref="@FluentValidations" EditContext="@EditContext" HandlerType="typeof(FluentValidationHandler)" ValidateOnLoad="false">
    <TextEdit @bind-Text="@description">
  </Validations>
</EditForm>
```

The C# code behind in my question does not need to be changed

```
private LibraryBook libraryBook;
private EditContext EditContext;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    EditContext = new EditContext(libraryBook);
    EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;
}

private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff when libraryBook has changed
}
```